# How can I implement a non-cached file copy using VB.NET 2005?

Tags: vb.net, file

I have a program I wrote that copies select files from one remote computer to another.
The set up I for testing is, one computer(a) at home running the program connected to my work's network via VPN and two computers(b,c) at work side by side on the same network. I am trying to copy the files on computer b to computer c, while the program is running on computer a.

The only thing wrong with this is, the files seem to be caching to a temp folder on computer a then going to computer c. When it should be going straight from computer b to computer c. Is there a way to keep the files from trying to cache on the computer running the app?

Answer (score 0):

Well, a couple of things you could try... I don't know if they will fit exactly for you;

- Remote into one of the work computers, say B, - via RDC, VNC or something similar - and then copy the file from B to C from directly ON B.
- Look into the tool psexec. This was published by sysinternals as part of their pstools suite. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx . This allows you, via command prompt, to connect to a remote machine and run commands directly on the remote machine from your machine.

HTH - CheerZ!

Comment: Trying to automate move the files to free up time for doing other tasks, and psexec is blocked from being used in out network.

Comment: is the move something which is done regularly, that you could write a cmd/batch file to put on the one work machine and put it in as a scheduled task?